# How to sort an array of objects (classes)?

Tags: c#, arrays, class, sorting

I'm trying to sort an array of objects with `Array.Sort`, but get an InvalidOperationException. As i have read i'm trying to sort a complex object and I need to use a `IComparable <T>` comparsion interface, but I don't understand how it works.

There is my code:

```
     public class C
     {
         public int I { get; set; }
     }

     static void Main(string[] args)
     {
         C[] classes = new C[100000];
         Random rand = new Random();
         for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
         {
            classes[i] = new C { I = rand.Next(1, 100000) };
         }
     
         Array.Sort<C>(classes); // Here I get an exception
     }
```

Comment: Just implement the interface IComparable<C> on your class C. Nothing too fancy or complicated. You can let the intellisense do all the work and write down the logic about how to do the actual comparison in the CompareTo method.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. "I need to use a IComparable <T> comparsion interface, but I don't understand how it works." Well, did you read the documentation for `IComparable<T>`? Did you try putting `c# sorting tutorial` or `c# icomparable tutorial` into a search engine? Please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592.

Comment: Fundamentally, the question you have to answer is: "Given two `C`s, what is the rule that says which one is 'smaller'?" The language will not guess your intent here. You must write code that implements that rule. You use the interface in order to *signal* that your code is implementing that rule.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should explain to .Net *how to compare* classes:

```
...
// having a and b instances we should compare I properties
Array.Sort<C>(classes, (a, b) => a.I.CompareTo(b.I)); 
...
```

Or you can make `class C` *comparable* (in order `Array.Sort<C>(classes);` to start working):

```
public class C : IComparable<C> {
  public int I { get; set; }

  public int CompareTo(C other) {
    if (null == other)
      return 1;

    return I.CompareTo(other.I);  
  }
}
```